# Shape mismatch when developing Autoencoder using Kears?

Tags: keras

I've tried to create an autoencoder using Keras, but as the input is not symmetric (21, 11), the summary is show in below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qldUr.png)

I've tried zeropadding and cropping2d, but no one could help to trim by one. Is any idea to make the decoder to output (21, 11, 1)? Thank you

Comment: Anyone can help?